# Execute bash in java

Tags: java, bash

Wen i try to run this code :

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "printf '%s'\n"+videoPath+"./"+"*.mp4 >"+"mylist.txt"}; 

processBuilder.command(cmd);
```

I get some error:

> /bin/bash: line 1:
>   /home/gilles/eclipse-workspace/informationGewinnungApp/videotool/outputs/./info.mp4:
>   cannot execute binary file: Exec format error 126

Comment: Too little information given, output not formatted properly and possibly offtopic. Error code usually means incompatible architectures.

Comment: Seems your bash installation doesn't know how to execute `.mp4` files.

Comment: Watch your quotes for the `printf` statement.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the `\` is not being escaped correctly; add an extra slash there, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Andreas: Are you aware of **any** bash which would be "know" how to execute a audio file?

Comment: @user1934428 It is possible to setup run-by-extension, similar to how Windows does it, such that all `.xxx` files are execute by running a particular command with the given file as argument. E.g. in my Windows, if I type `foo.pdf` in command prompt, it automatically opens Adobe Acrobat Reader to show the PDF file.

Comment: @Andreas : I am not aware that any operating system duplicates Windows' oddity to derive from the filename what to do with an executable file. I think something like this could be implemented in the bash source code, but then bash would behave differently from any other tool on Linux (zsh, Perl, C) when it comes for creating a child process. And, what should it do if I decide to call my bash script `foo.m4a`, and have a proper `#!/bin/bash` at the first line? Should the extension "win", or should the normal file execution mechanism be used?

Comment: @user1934428 I'm not a Linux pro, but I just saw this one recently: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Binfmt_misc_for_Java

Comment: @Andreas : Of course one *can* fiddle around with the file loader. I just don't see the point. You would just be incompatible with every Linux which does not have this Kernel patch. There is already a mechanism in Linux, which allows to run commands by their type; it's just that the "type" is not related to the file name, but to its [magic number](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-magic-numbers-in-linux/).

Comment: @user1934428 So what you're saying is that the magic number is missing or corrupt or not configured for the MP4 file in the question? So you main complaint to my original comment is that I should have said "execute MP4 files" instead of "execute `.mp4` files"?

Comment: No. I don't think there is a magic number for mp4, because there is no "mp4 executable file format". You could, in theory, create a magic number for the cases you are thinking, in a similar way as `#!` in a script works, but I don't think it would make much sense. What should be the "default action" to be done with a mp4 file, after all?

Comment: @Andreas : When you want to *run* something, you run a program. This can be some binary, in which case Linux needs to know how to load the binary (that's why different executable formats of binaries had historically different magic numbers), or it may be a script supplied in the source code (this is signalled by the #! magic number), and the executable to run is the script interpreter, which in this case is the string after the  `#!`. Data files don't fit well into this scheme.

Answer (score 2):

The \n in your string is expanded into a newline. Hence bash sees two commands,

```
printf %s
..../info.mp4
```

Do it either as

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "printf '%s' "+videoPath+"./"+"*.mp4 >"+"mylist.txt"};
```

Or

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "echo "+videoPath+"./"+"*.mp4 >"+"mylist.txt"};
```

But: Why don't you want to use a bash child process, if you only want to create a new file containing a certain string? Wouldn't it be easier to do it directly from Java?

Comment: I would just use a FileWriter and write stuff to the mylist.txt after getting a file list with Java. JM2C.